# Hidden default android keyboard in mobile app Android studio

Tags: android-studio

is there any way I can remove the standard Android keyboard when clicking on input fields?
I want to make my own graphical keyboard from the buttons below
And if I can remove , where can I find ?

Tried to change the flags in Configuration.java, but it didn't work